# How can I translate console application to SWING framework?

Tags: java, swing, console, jframe

I have a working class HoltWinters, which is main in my package. It is a console application. I search the one folder on my computer, read names of all the files in this folder. Then I ask the user to print the name of the file he wants to use in the programm. After it I save this name as string and use this file for the forecast.

But i need to do it via windows application. As i understand it, i need to create new java JFrame (I use NetBeans, so I've done using their constructor). I put there 1 JText field and 1 JButton. I want next things to happen when i press the button:

1. the text from the JText field is read and saved as String
2. the method HoltWinters.main is run, using String from the JText

But i don't understand how to do it at all:( I think, maybe i have some mistake in my logic or it should be done differently, but it's my first not console application and i don't know what to do:-(

That is my HoltWinters class:

```
package holtwinters;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
/**
St[i] = alpha * y[i] / It[i - period] + (1.0 - alpha) * (St[i - 1] + Bt[i - 1]) - overall
Bt[i] = gamma * (St[i] - St[i - 1]) + (1 - gamma) * Bt[i - 1] - trend
It[i] = beta * y[i] / St[i] + (1.0 - beta) * It[i - period] - season
Ft[i + m] = (St[i] + (m * Bt[i])) * It[i - period + m] - predictions
*/

/**
*
* @author Jane
*/
public class HoltWinters {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  /*
 y - Time series data.
 alpha - coeff
 beta - coeff
 gamma - coeff
 period - 24 hours
 m - future data
 debug -  debug values for testing
 */

public static void main( String[] args )
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String path = "C:\\Users\\Jane\\Desktop";

    File f = new File (path);
    String[] list=f.list();
    for (String str : list){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Input n: ");
    String sn=in.readLine();
    String[] ary = sn.split(" ");
    String name = null;


    for(String file1: list) {
        for (String ary1: ary) {
            if (ary1.equals(file1)) {
                System.out.println("found!");
                name = sn;

            }
        }
    }

    File file = new File( path+"\\"+name );

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream( file ), "UTF-8"
            )
    );
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {



        try {
            Long y = Long.valueOf(line);
           // System.out.println(y);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Неверный формат строки!");
        }
    }

  //  long data = Long.valueOf(line);
  //  int change = (int) data;
  //  long [] y = new long [change];

    int period = 24;
    int m = 5;

    long[] y = new long[144];
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path+"\\"+name));

        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {

            y[i] = scanner.nextLong();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double sum_origin = 0;
    int k=0;
    do {
        sum_origin = sum_origin + y[k];
        k++;
    } while (k<24);

//searching for alpha
    double alpha = 0.01;
    double a = 0.01;
    double x=sum_origin;
    double q;
    do {
        double beta = 0.3;
        double gamma = 0.3;
        double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, a, beta, gamma,
                period, m);
        double sum_pre = sum(prediction);

          q = sum_origin - sum_pre;
        if (q<=x) {
            x=q;
            alpha = a;
        }
        a = a +0.01;
    } while (a<0.99);

//searching for beta
    double beta = 0.01;
    double b = 0.01;
    double x1=1000000;
    double q1;
    do {
        double gamma = 0.3;
        double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, alpha, b, gamma,
                period, m);
        double sum_pre = sum(prediction);
        q1 = sum_origin - sum_pre;
        if (q1<=x1) {
            x1=q1;
            beta = b;
        }
        b = b +0.01;
    } while (b<0.99);

//searching for gamma
    double gamma = 0.01;
    double g = 0.01;
    double x2=1000000;
    double q2;
    do {
        double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, alpha, beta, g,
                period, m);
        double sum_pre = sum(prediction);
        q2 = sum_origin - sum_pre;
        if (q2<=x2) {
            x2=q2;
            gamma = g;
        }
        g = g +0.01;
    } while (g<0.99);


    System.out.println(alpha);
    System.out.println(beta);
    System.out.println(gamma);


    double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, alpha, beta, gamma,
            period, m);
   for(int i = period; i <= prediction.length - 1; i++) {
           System.out.println(prediction[i] + "  ");
    }
    br.close();


    File flt = new File("C:\\Users\\Jane\\Desktop\\003003_prediction.txt");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(flt)));
    for(int i = period; i <= prediction.length - 1; i++) {
        out.println(prediction[i] + "  ");
    }

    out.flush();


}


public static double sum(double...values) {
    double result = 0;
    for (double value:values)
        result += value;
    return result;
}



public static double[] forecast(long[] y, double alpha, double beta,
                                double gamma, int period, int m, boolean debug) {




    validateArguments(y, alpha, beta, gamma, period, m);

    int seasons = y.length / period;
    double a0 = calculateInitialLevel(y, period);
    double b0 = calculateInitialTrend(y, period);
    double[] initialSeasonalIndices = calculateSeasonalIndices(y, period,
            seasons);

    if (debug) {
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Total observations: %d, Seasons %d, Periods %d", y.length,
                seasons, period));
        System.out.println("Initial level value a0: " + a0);
        System.out.println("Initial trend value b0: " + b0);
        printArray("Seasonal Indices: ", initialSeasonalIndices);
    }

    double[] forecast = calculateHoltWinters(y, a0, b0, alpha, beta, gamma,
            initialSeasonalIndices, period, m, debug);

    if (debug) {
        printArray("Forecast", forecast);
    }

    return forecast;
}

public static double[] forecast(long[] y, double alpha, double beta,
                                double gamma, int period, int m) {
    return forecast(y, alpha, beta, gamma, period, m, false);
}

/**
 validate input
 */
private static void validateArguments(long[] y, double alpha, double beta,
                                      double gamma, int period, int m) {
    if (y == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of y should be not null");
    }

    if(m <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of m must be greater than 0.");
    }

    if(m > period){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of m must be <= period.");
    }

    if((alpha < 0.0) || (alpha > 1.0)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of Alpha should satisfy 0.0 <= alpha <= 1.0");
    }

    if((beta < 0.0) || (beta > 1.0)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of Beta should satisfy 0.0 <= beta <= 1.0");
    }

    if((gamma < 0.0) || (gamma > 1.0)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value of Gamma should satisfy 0.0 <= gamma <= 1.0");
    }
}

/**
 the Holt-Winters equations
 */
private static double[] calculateHoltWinters(long[] y, double a0, double b0,
                                             double alpha, double beta, double gamma,
                                             double[] initialSeasonalIndices, int period, int m, boolean debug) {

    double[] St = new double[y.length];
    double[] Bt = new double[y.length];
    double[] It = new double[y.length];
    double[] Ft = new double[y.length + m];

    // Initialize base values
    St[1] = a0;
    Bt[1] = b0;

    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        It[i] = initialSeasonalIndices[i];
    }

    // Start calculations
    for (int i = 2; i < y.length; i++) {

        // Calculate overall smoothing
        if ((((i - period) >= 0) & (It[i]!=0))) {
            St[i] = alpha * y[i] / It[i - period] + (1.0 - alpha)
                    * (St[i - 1] + Bt[i - 1]);
        }
        else {
            St[i] = alpha * y[i] + (1.0 - alpha) * (St[i - 1] + Bt[i - 1]);
        }

        // Calculate trend smoothing
        Bt[i] = gamma * (St[i] - St[i - 1]) + (1 - gamma) * Bt[i - 1];

        // Calculate seasonal smoothing
        if ((i - period) >= 0) {
            It[i] = beta * y[i] / St[i] + (1.0 - beta) * It[i - period];
        }

        // Calculate forecast
        if (((i + m) >= period)) {
            Ft[i + m] = Math.abs(((St[i] + (m * Bt[i])) * It[i - period + m])*(-1));
        }

        if (debug) {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "i = %d, y = %d, S = %f, Bt = %f, It = %f, F = %f", i,
                    y[i], St[i], Bt[i], It[i], Ft[i]));
        }
    }
    return Ft;
}

/**
 Initial Level value - St[1]
 */
public static double calculateInitialLevel(long[] y, int period) {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        sum += (y[i]);
    }
    return sum / (period*period);
}

/**
 Initial trend - Bt[1]
 */
public static double calculateInitialTrend(long[] y, int period) {

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        sum += Math.abs((y[period + i] - y[i]));
    }
    return sum / (period * period);
}

/**
 Seasonal Indices.
 */
public static double[] calculateSeasonalIndices(long[] y, int period,
                                                int seasons) {

    double[] seasonalAverage = new double[seasons];
    double[] seasonalIndices = new double[period];

    double[] averagedObservations = new double[y.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < seasons; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < period; j++) {
            seasonalAverage[i] += y[(i * period) + j];
        }
        seasonalAverage[i] /= period;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < seasons; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < period; j++) {
            averagedObservations[(i * period) + j] = y[(i * period) + j]
                    / seasonalAverage[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < seasons; j++) {
            seasonalIndices[i] += averagedObservations[(j * period) + i];
        }
        seasonalIndices[i] /= seasons;
    }

    return seasonalIndices;
}

/**
 method to print array values
 */
private static void printArray(String description, double[] data) {
    System.out.println(description);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
}
```

}

This is JFrame

```
package holtwinters;

/**
 *
 * @author Jane
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextField1.setText("Введите номер банкомата");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Ввести");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 280, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(136, 136, 136)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("Button pressed") ;
    HoltWinters other = new HoltWinters();


}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the `JFrame` and the other components that you speak about?

Comment: Before doing any GUI creation, you must change and improve your console program. At present it's little more than a single *huge* static main method with a couple other smaller static methods, and there's no way that something so structured can be safely ported to a GUI. What you want to do is to create true OOP-compliant classes, classes with state (non-static instance fields) and behaviors (non-static methods), classes that would constitute your program's ***MODEL***. Then test these classes by using them in a console program, and if they test OK, try to create a GUI that uses them.

Comment: @JaneMakedonskaya I totally agree with Hovercraft. The question as it stands is too broad for stackoverflow standards.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how can i do it? maybe you can advise something??

Comment: @JaneMakedonskaya: There is no "one-size-fits-all" solutions. Have you learned object-oriented programming principles? If so, then apply them to your code above. If not, then get a decent book on object-oriented design principles and study. [For example](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/booklist.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you, i learned basic principles but i think i learn to do more.

Comment: Could you please post some example files which you intend to scan for that `long[] y`? How do you want to display the results? Or is it just that `003003_prediction.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                yourButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


public void yourButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                String yourText = jTextField1.getText();
                HoltWinters tempHolt = new HoltWinters();


  tempHolt.methodToRun(yourText);
            }
```

you need to change your code a lot, start with dao, model and gui layers (packages).